# I want to understand the following code lines defined in the function

Tags: python, machine-learning, hash, firebase-mlkit

I am a beginner in python and machine learning. while doing a project from the book "hands-on ML with sci-kit learn and TF" I came across this way of creating test-set using hashlib.
Can you please help me understand what this logic of the return statement, step by step-

```
def test_set_check(identifier, test_ratio, hash):
    return hash(np.int64(identifier)).digest()[-1]<256 * test_ratio
```

Comment: If you're a python beginner. At least first get familiar with python and it's libraries, then get into machine learning. You will understand many concepts in much better way.

Comment: @xxbinxx, thanks for the suggestion. Yes, actually I am devoting more time on python and its concepts but wanted to speed up my learning ..

Comment: (y) all the best buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `hash` is something from `hashlib`:

- cast `identifier` to a (numpy) 64bit integer
- hash the cast `identifier`
- get the value of the last **byte** from the hash
- compare that value to `(256 * test_ratio)`
- return the result of The comparison

Comment: yes, hash is from hashlib.
Thank you.
why would we want to index it as " [-1] "

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me why do we need to index [-1] at the end?

Comment: the `[-1]` gets you the last item in a list/string, I can't tell you why you need the to compare the last byte as i don't know what your algorithm is